# GPU Utilization Interpretation

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have tested a kernel with the NVIDIA Profiler which outputs the following:

[image]

We have launched the kernel with 256 blocks and 256 threads.
As far as I understand, the grafic shows three sections, one for Warps , one for Registers, one for Shared Memory and each section has a calculated "Block Limit", from which the one in the register section is the smallest and most limiting value.
Obviously the kernel is register bound and we can launch only 4 blocks simultaneously on one SM. That is what the Profiler says. I am utterly asking myself about the following thing:

A GTX 780 Ti, has 192 cores in one SM, how is it possible that 4 blocks * 256 threads = 1024 Threads can be launched simultaneously? What does this "simultaneously" mean anyway in CUDA terms? Does it mean, that 4 blocks can be scheduled in the scheduler at the same time and the SM executes  instructions in lock-step fashion from warps of one single block at the time. The word simultaneously is  somewhat confuse?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The number of registers per thread which you are using at the moment limits the number of blocks which can be simultaneously (at the same time) executed on one SM. Therefore GPU is not fully utilized. Remember that the relationship between registers, blocks and thread is a 3-way relationship. This doc http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GPU is a latency-hiding machine, and the latency-hiding involves scheduling various threads (instructions) on various execution units, at each cycle/issue slot.  In order to hide latency best, the GPU likes to have many more available threads to choose instructions from than there are execution units on the SM.

So in a given cycle, it might be that there are only 192 (or fewer, probably) execution units scheduled by the warp scheduler(s), but in the very next cycle/issue slot, more instructions can be scheduled.  In order to facilitate this process, we want to have as many threads/warps/blocks "available" for scheduling, as possible.  The "simultaneous" here refers to the number of threads/warps/blocks that are "open" on the SM and "available to be scheduled".  It does not refer to how many actual instructions get issued in any issue slot, nor does it refer to the number of "cores" or "execution units" on the SM.

The number of threads/warps/blocks that can be "opened" on the SM at any given time (so as to be available for scheduling purposes) may be limited by the resource usage of the threadblocks in question.  Threadblocks with high register usage, for example, may limit the total number of threadblocks that can be "open" on the SM, because the SM must allocate a full register set to every "open" threadblock.

Since GTX 780 Ti uses the GK110 GPU, the [GK110 white paper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf) may be of interest.

Comment: thanks for the lovely explanations. you wrote "but in the very next cycle/issue slot, more instructions can be scheduled." --> what do you mean with more? more than 192 instructions are scheduled? if so, it is still true that only a maximum of 192 threads from one block can execute an instruction at the same time, since there are 192 cores available?

Comment: The GPU execution units are pipelined.  By "more" I meant new instructions (as compared to those issued previously), not "more than 192".  Since previously issued instructions can be in various stages of the pipeline execution, saying things like "only a maximum of 192 threads from one block can execute an instruction at the same time" is not sensible.  At any given instant, various instructions are executing in the pipeline.  Regarding *what can be issued in a single cycle/issue slot*, it's still not perfectly correct, because there are more than 192 execution units in a Kepler SM.

Comment: The 192 "cores" refer approximately to the SP units.  There are other execution units besides SP units.  But there are only 4 warp schedulers, each of which can dual-issue a warp's worth of instructions. So the max theoretical is 8*32 = 256 thread instructions issued.  This max theoretical is not usually achieved in practice.  And even if it were, the 256 thread instructions could not be all of the same type (e.g. SP floating point multiply).